# Análise sintática da expressão "em um país muito distante"

Tags: português-brasileiro, sintaxe

Olá! Como se analise sintaticamente a expressão "em um país muito distante"?

Segue a frase completa:

---

*Era uma vez, em um país muito distante, um mercador tão venturoso em suas atividades.*

---

1. Esta expressão classifica-se como um adjunto adverbial de tempo referente à "era uma vez"?
2. Essa expressão deve ser analisada como um todo ou cabe análise dos seus termos internos? Por exemplo:

   - "país": núcleo;
   - "um": adjunto adnominal referente à "país";
   - "distante": adjunto adnominal referente à "país";
   - "muito": adjunto adverbial de intensidade referente à "distante"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem-vindo, Bruno!

Nessa frase, a expressão "em um país muito distante" é o **adjunto adverbial de lugar** de "Era uma vez".

Lembre-se de que o adjunto adverbial é um termo acessório da oração que indica alguma circunstância (tempo, lugar, modo, causa, finalidade etc.). A circunstância indicada por "em um país muito distante" não é de *tempo* como você pensou.

Comment: Obrigado Luana! Realmente, foi um erro bobo meu. Está claro que é de lugar. Mas ainda fiquei com uma dúvida porque entendo que o adjunto adverbial modifica um verbo, mas você disse que ele se refere a oração inteira. No caso, não seria um adjunto adverbial de lugar referente à "era uma vez"? Pois estou tratando a expressão "era uma vez" como sinônimo do verbo "existiu".

Comment: Isso mesmo, Bruno! Irei editar minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigado! Só mais uma coisa, nós podemos detalhar a análise do adjunto adverbial analisando cada parte deste termo como eu fiz no item 2 da minha pergunta?

Comment: @BrunoCarneiro Sim, você também poderá analisar cada termo de um adjunto, porém essa análise não terá ligação com os demais termos da frase (verbo, sujeito etc).

Comment: Como Valdeir Psr explicou, podemos sim fazer essa análise, Bruno.